# Visualize the Result of a Hough Transformation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, hough-transform

I am currently programming a **laser 3D-sensor** which provides me with **edge points (X,Y,Z) in a 2D array** as a result. The coordinates are used to perform a **Hough-transform**. The result in Rho and Theta is output to my console.
My question now is whether I can visualise this result, to check for correctness. I have thought of the library **OpenCV**, but I am not familiar with its programming and have only seen functions and examples that have transformed and visualised images specified by a file path. Maybe someone can tell me if OpenCV supports a function that allows the visualisation of the Rho and Theta values as raw input, or if there are other possibilities.

---

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You can generate a .bmp file fairly easily and open it with whatever program opens .bmp files on your operating system

Comment: Was the updated reply work? If the reply helped , you can mark it as answer. It will help people  who have the same problem.  If not, please provide detailed error information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw your points in an OpenCv image as a contour , then apply Hough transform as follow:

```
cv::Mat dst;
cv::drawContours(dst, contours, -1, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
 // contours is your 2D vector)

vector<Vec2f> lines; // will hold theta and rho
HoughLines(dst, lines, 1, cv::CV_PI/180, 150, 0, 0 ); 
for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
{
 float rho = lines[i][0], theta = lines[i][1];
 std::cout << "rho = " << rho << " theta = " << theta << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Hi, I would like to try your solution. How do I define "Scalar" ? I get a message that it is not defined.  
With kind regards
Simon

Comment: I've edited the answer, you need to use the scope cv::Scalar or you can use `using namespace cv` to simplify your test.